# Robot Framework - Call *.robot script from other *.robot script with parameters

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

Let's say I have 2 robot framework script (x.robot ans y.robot),
is there a way that x.robot script will execute y.robot with different parameters?
Meaning I don't want duplicate *.robot scripts but one script that run with different parameters each time.

I'm using Python3

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way that x.robot script will execute y.robot with different parameters?

No, there is not. Robot has no ability to run a test suite from another test suite. Your only option is to spawn a new process, which means the result of this second test suite will be written to a different log file.

Comment: I was faced to a similar issue. I decided to spawn a new robot process from a robot file using keyword `Run Process` (writing to a different outputdir). **Do you think that will be problematic (e.g. due to shared resources by robot or similar)?**